# video playback problems after reinstalling 20.04

Tags: 20.04, video, playback

I just reinstalled 20.04 after disc crash.  Before reinstalling I had no problems with video playback.  Now several (but not all) videos produce "this video cannot be played".   EG parliament TV cannot be played, whilst most YouTube videos play fine.

I have read the help pages but nothing helps.  Colin Rourke

Comment: Maybe before you had additional codecs installed.

Comment: Can you give me some hints on installing the missing codecs? Colin

Comment: The hint of looking for video codecs lead me to this page https://itsfoss.com/install-media-codecs-ubuntu/ which fixed it -- (at least twitter now runs, which it didn't before).  Colin

Comment: That's exactly what I was about to suggest.